# how to automatically change to pytest temporary directory for all doctests

Tags: python, testing, pytest, doctest

I would like to change to pytest temporary directory at the beginning of each doctest and I was wondering if there is a way to do it automatically without starting every doctests with:

```
>>> tmp = getfixture('tmpdir')                                                                                            
>>> old = tmp.chdir()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is doable:

`conftest.py`:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _docdir(request):

    # Trigger ONLY for the doctests.
    doctest_plugin = request.config.pluginmanager.getplugin("doctest")
    if isinstance(request.node, doctest_plugin.DoctestItem):

        # Get the fixture dynamically by its name.
        tmpdir = request.getfuncargvalue('tmpdir')

        # Chdir only for the duration of the test.
        with tmpdir.as_cwd():
            yield

    else:
        # For normal tests, we have to yield, since this is a yield-fixture.
        yield
```

`test_me.py`:

```
import os.path

# Regular tests are NOT chdir'ed.
def test_me():
    moddir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    assert os.getcwd() == moddir
```

`import_me.py`:

```
import os, os.path

# Doctests are chdir'ed.
def some_func():
    """
    >>> 2+3
    5
    >>> os.getcwd().startswith('/private/')
    True
    """
    pass
```

Hopefully, this gives you an idea how to detect doctests, and how to chdir temporarily for the test duration.

---

In addition, you can also put a breakpoint and investigate the content of `request.node.dtest` in the fixture. That way, you can add optional comments/marks to the docstring or to the doctest line, and behave accordingly:

```
(Pdb++) pp request.node.dtest.docstring
"\n    >>> 2+3\n    5\n    >>> os.getcwd().startswith('/private/')\n    True\n    "

(Pdb++) pp request.node.dtest.examples[0].source
'2+3\n'
(Pdb++) pp request.node.dtest.examples[0].want
'5\n'

(Pdb++) pp request.node.dtest.examples[1].source
"os.getcwd().startswith('/private/')\n"
(Pdb++) pp request.node.dtest.examples[1].want
'True\n'
(Pdb++) pp request.node.dtest.examples[1].exc_msg
None
```